# How to set the library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, handler, android-support-library

I am trying to set a waveInApp library http://www.materialup.com/posts/waveinapp
I have declared all the required thing .The app
 working but the background  wave is not working .I am not able to set the wave  function as a beginner in android development .
I am able to set the all the basic things including the media player.
Here I am not able to set the speech recognization handler
Here is what I have done

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.AudioVisualization;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.DbmHandler;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.SpeechRecognizerDbmHandler;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.VisualizerDbmHandler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private AudioVisualization audioVisualization;
private Context context;
private ImageButton button1,button2;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    audioVisualization = (AudioVisualization)findViewById(R.id.visualizer_view);
    button1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    button2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"pause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    VisualizerDbmHandler vizualizerHandler = DbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(getContext(), 0);
    audioVisualization.linkTo(vizualizerHandler);
    // set speech recognizer handler
    SpeechRecognizerDbmHandler speechRecHandler = DbmHandler.Factory.newSpeechRecognizerHandler(context);
    speechRecHandler.innerRecognitionListener(...);
    audioVisualization.linkTo(speechRecHandler);
}
});
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    audioVisualization.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    audioVisualization.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
 }
```

So how to set the above handeler. I am not able to set the connect audio visualization view to audio output . How to set the following method with the media player

```
// set speech recognizer handler
SpeechRecognizerDbmHandler speechRecHandler = DbmHandler.Factory.newSpeechRecognizerHandler(context);
speechRecHandler.innerRecognitionListener(...);
audioVisualization.linkTo(speechRecHandler);

// set audio visualization handler. This will REPLACE previously set speech recognizer handler
VisualizerDbmHandler vizualizerHandler = DbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(getContext(), 0);
audioVisualization.linkTo(vizualizerHandler);
```

Except this all are working.any hint or advice will be helpfull.
I tried to search

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.AudioVisualization;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.DbmHandler;
import com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.SpeechRecognizerDbmHandler;


public class SpeechRecognitionFragment extends Fragment {

public static SpeechRecognitionFragment newInstance() {
    return new SpeechRecognitionFragment();
}

private AudioVisualization audioVisualization;
private Button btnRecognize;
private SpeechRecognizerDbmHandler handler;
private boolean recognizing;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gles, container, false);
    audioVisualization = (AudioVisualization) view.findViewById(R.id.visualizer_view);
    btnRecognize = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_recognize);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    btnRecognize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (recognizing) {
                handler.stopListening();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getContext().getPackageName());
                handler.startListening(intent);
            }
            btnRecognize.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    handler = DbmHandler.Factory.newSpeechRecognizerHandler(getContext());
    handler.innerRecognitionListener(new SimpleRecognitionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            super.onReadyForSpeech(params);
            onStartRecognizing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            super.onResults(results);
            onStopRecognizing();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            super.onError(error);
            onStopRecognizing();

        }
    });
    audioVisualization.linkTo(handler);
}

private void onStopRecognizing() {
    recognizing = false;
    btnRecognize.setText(R.string.start_recognition);
    btnRecognize.setEnabled(true);
}

private void onStartRecognizing() {
    btnRecognize.setText(R.string.stop_recognition);
    btnRecognize.setEnabled(true);
    recognizing = true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    audioVisualization.release();
    super.onDestroyView();
}

private static class SimpleRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener {

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
    }
}
}
```

from https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/cleveroad/example/SpeechRecognitionFragment.java 
So can some one tell me why fragment is used and how I can set this in my main activity?

Comment: thank you for this question.. i found something new.. i will definatly implementing this..

Answer (score 1):

```
I know i am late to post this answer...but for future use try this
check my code you will find your answer 
first of all in the liberay you have to make some changes in your xml.


<com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.GLAudioVisualizationView
    android:id="@+id/visualizer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:av_bubblesSize= "@dimen/bubble_size"
    app:av_bubblesRandomizeSizes= "true"
    app:av_wavesHeight= "@dimen/wave_height"
    app:av_wavesFooterHeight="@dimen/footer_height"
    app:av_wavesCount="7"
    app:av_layersCount="4" />
```

then

```
  private VisualizerDbmHandler handler;
  MediaPlayer mp ;
  private AudioVisualization audioVisualization;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View ve = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cat, container, false);
    ibCapture = (ImageButton) ve.findViewById(R.id.ibCapture);
    audioVisualization =  (AudioVisualization)ve.findViewById(R.id.visualizer_view);
   hell();
    return ve;
}



    ibCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (bool) {
                bool = false;
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.blackcat);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                handler = VisualizerDbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(getContext(),mp);
                audioVisualization.linkTo(handler);
                mp.start();

            ((home)getActivity()).vis();
            } else {
                bool = true;
                ((home)getActivity()).visgone();
                stopPlaying();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
audioVisualization = (AudioVisualization) glAudioVisualizationView;
```

With

```
 audioVisualization = (AudioVisualization)findViewById(R.id.glAudioVisualizationView);
```

`glAudioVisualizationView` should be id of `AudioVisualization` in your layout file

Answer (score 0):

define

```
private AudioVisualization audioVisualization;
```

initialize it

```
 audioVisualization = (AudioVisualization) view.findViewById(R.id.visualizer_view);
```

for speech use below code

```
SpeechRecognizerDbmHandler speechRecHandler = DbmHandler.Factory.newSpeechRecognizerHandler(getContext());
                speechRecHandler.innerRecognitionListener();
                audioVisualization.linkTo(speechRecHandler);

                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getContext().getPackageName());
                speechRecHandler.startListening(intent);
```

for a media on your device use below code, Sandeep Singh [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40043257/7569106)

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.blackcat);
                mp.setLooping(true);
                handler = VisualizerDbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(getContext(),mp);
                audioVisualization.linkTo(handler);
                mp.start();
```